# Probability distribution of $Z=X_1\,I(U<p) + X_2\, I(U\ge p)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two (possibly dependent) real random variables with distribution function $F_1$ and $F_2$, respectively.
Let also $U$ be a random variable that is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$ and independent of $X_1$ and $X_2$.
Define the random variable $$Z=X_1\,I(U<p) + X_2\, I(U\ge p),$$
where $p\in[0,1]$ and $I(A)$ stands for the indicator function of event $A$.
What is the distribution of $Z$?

**Tentative answer.**
Simply conditioning on $U$, I get that the distribution of $Z$ is $pF_1 + (1-p) F_2$. Is this correct?
What it's not clear to me is that the distribution of $Z$ (according to my argument) would still be $pF_1 + (1-p) F_2$ if $X_1$ and $X_2$ were independent, so that dependence here does not seem to play a role and I am missing why that is true (if it is).

Comment: Yes, the distribution _function_ of $Z$ is $pF_1+(1-p)F_2$ regardless of whether $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent or not.

Comment: @StefanHansen thanks! is there any intuition?

Comment: By definition, $Z=X_1$ on the set $[U<p]$ which has probability $p$ of occuring and $Z=X_2$ on the set $[U\geq p]$ which has probability $(1-p)$ of occuring.